# How do I change the alpha channel of a color in a color picker dialog?

Tags: c#, colors, alpha, color-picker

I've made a Color Picker in C#, but someone asked me to make an Alpha property. So far it works great, except for the part of the Alpha property itself.

The question is: How do I change the `ColorDialog.Color.A` by scrolling up and down a ScrollBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ValueChanged` event on the `ScrollBar` class.